# Centos 6, PHP, apache, CPanel memory_limit won't increase

Tags: php, apache, centos, out-of-memory, memory-limit

When running a certain PHP script which needs a lot of memory I'm getting the "Out of memory (allocated 137887744) (tried to allocate 93 bytes) in..." error.

I've tried increasing this in all places I know how..

php.ini, duplicated php.ini into local folder and increased here. ini_set() on in the script file etc.

phpinfo says memory is 512M.

Is there any suggestions of what I can do to increase the memory?

Thanks,
Martin.

Comment: When you change your PHP.ini `memory_limit`, did you restarted your Apache?

Comment: "Out of memory" sounds more like the script might be *actually* out of memory, not hitting the memory limit. Do you have some other quota in place on your server?

Comment: Yeah, I restarted my server every time.
This is what I'm unsure of, if there is a quota.. this could be it. I will email the hosting and see what they have to say.

I believe suPHP is running, could this have a memory cap ?

Comment: if phpinfo() is showing 512M memory limit, I would cringe with fear.  That is a lot of memory being requested for a PHP script to run.

Comment: If I wanted to list 20,000 companies on a page, would I not need a lot of memory? I set it to 512 for testing purposes too though.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't because of PHP per-se (as Pekka says in the comments). The error message from the ini setting references "Allowed Memory" being exceeded, and this is a straight "out of memory". Changing the ini setting won't work.

Priority number 1 is to check your script. Unless you handling images or some very large files, you shouldn't get anywhere near that memory requirements. Just double check that bit first.

Option 2: You need to allow for memory for Apache / PHP to play in (assuming you can't optomise your script. You are probably running a VPS or other restriction on the memory your user can use - there is a file called "limits.conf" (in security directory, `man limits.conf` for more) and also a memory management application smem that can restrict per user. So go to your hosting and get those increased - but if you're on a shared server, they will be asking why and probably want you to upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps someone. I had the same issue. Everything I read indicated this was caused by RLimitMEM settings in Apache. This did not solve the issue for me. After days of pulling my hair out, I finally fixed the issue by discovering and editing /usr/local/apache/conf/rlimit-config